# Generate information cards with titles

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, generation

You must take input in the form of

```
title|line1|line2|(...)|line[n]
```

And output an information card. It's hard to explain how to make the card, so here's a quick example:

Input

```
1234567890|12345|1234567890123|pie|potato|unicorn
```

Output

```
/===============\
|  1234567890   |
|===============|
| 12345         |
| 1234567890123 |
| pie           |
| potato        |
| unicorn       |
\---------------/
```

Detailed specifications:

- The title must be centered (if there are an odd number of characters you can decide whether to put an extra space after or before it).
- The remaining lines must be left-aligned.
- All of them must have at least one space of padding before and after.
- Each line must be the same length.
- The lines must be the smallest length possible in order to fit all of the text.
- The first and last character of each row (except for the first and last rows) must be a `|`.
- There must be a `/`, a row of `=`s, and a `\` in the line right before the title. (the first line)
- There must be a `|`, a row of `=`s. and a `|` in the line right after the title. (the third line)
- There must be a `\`, a row of `-`s, and a `/` in the last line.
- For the example input provided, your program's output must exactly match the example output provided.
- The input will always contain at least one `|`; your programs behaivior when a string like `badstring` is input does not matter.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest code in character count wins.

Comment: In python `input()` interprets the input as python code. Is it ok to use input and take the input in quotes, if so do we need to add 2 for the quotes?

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr I suppose that's okay, but add +2 for quotes then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### GolfScript, 97 characters

```
'|'/{'  ':!{1/*}:E~}%.{,}%$-1=:L'='*:§'/\\'E\(.,L\-)2/{!E}*L<'||':^E§^E@{!L*+L<^E}/L'-'*'\\/'E]n*
```

[Example](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OyIxMjM0NTY3ODkwfDEyMzQ1fDEyMzQ1Njc4OTAxMjN8cGllfHBvdGF0b3x1bmljb3JuIgoKJ3wnL3snICAnOiF7MS8qfTpFfn0lLnssfSUkLTE9OkwnPScqOsKnJy9cXCdFXCguLExcLSkyL3shRX0qTDwnfHwnOl5FwqdeRUB7IUwqK0w8XkV9L0wnLScqJ1xcLydFXW4qCg%3D%3D&run=true):

```
> 1234567890|12345|1234567890123|pie|potato|unicorn

/===============\
|   1234567890  |
|===============|
| 12345         |
| 1234567890123 |
| pie           |
| potato        |
| unicorn       |
\---------------/
```

Comment: `§` that's an interesting variable name. :P

Answer (score 4):

### Ruby, <s>153</s> <s>147</s> 140 characters

```
h,*d=s=gets.chop.split(?|)
puts"/%s\\
|%s|
|%s|"%[e=?=*k=2+l=s.map(&:size).max,h.center(k),e]
d.map{|x|puts"| %%-%ds |"%l%x}
$><<?\\+?-*k+?/
```

Double format string in the second-to-last line `:D`

Comment: `l=s.map(&:size).max` saves 4

Comment: Also no need for parentheses around `k=l+2` (2 chars), `center(k)` (2 chars), `k=2+l=s....` (2 chars).

Comment: @Howard I fixed the first one, but I'm not sure where you're seeing the second or third ones...?

Comment: `"| %s |"%h.center(l)` -> `"|%s|"%h.center(k)` which removes 2 spaces. And `l=s.map(&:size).max;e=?=*k=l+2"` -> `e=?=*k=2+l=s.map(&:size).max`

Comment: @How Thanks, but the last one will break if the title is the longest word. Fixed the first.

Comment: I can't see that it breaks anything. Also you can save more chars if you move the assignments (e.g. `s=` into the second line - 1 char and e=.. into the `%[e=...` thing - 2 chars).

Comment: For the second, I think Howard means change `center(l)` to `center l`, which saves a space.

Comment: @Howard If the title is the longest word with your improvement, it will lose the padding on both sides. The `s=` cannot be moved because it gives an error, but I did use your `e=` thing.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Then it parses as `h.center(l,e)`

Comment: @Doorknob but isn't `k` always 2 more than the length of the longest string? So it should still be padded.

Comment: @Vola Oh yes, good point. Edited

Comment: The `s=` thing can be fixed if you put parenthesis around, i.e. `h,*d=s=gets.chop.split(?|)` which is still one char shorter.

Answer (score 4):

## Python 2.7 - 168 = 166 + 2 for quotes.

This assumes we can accept the input with surrounding quotes, hence the possible +2. Either way +2 is better than the +4 required if you use `raw_input()` vs. just `input()`.

```
b="|"
s=input().split(b)
w=max(map(len,s))
x=w+2
S="| %s |"
print"\n".join(["/"+"="*x+"\\",S%s[0].center(w),b+"="*x+b]+[S%i.ljust(w)for i in s[1:]]+["\\"+"-"*x+"/"])
```

Thanks to Volatility for the `max(map(len,s))` tip. A very cool tip.

**edit:** Corrected top row problem.

And the above outputs this:

```
> python i.py
"1234567890|12345|1234567890123|pie|potato|unicorn"
/===============\
|   1234567890  |
|===============|
| 12345         |
| 1234567890123 |
| pie           |
| potato        |
| unicorn       |
\---------------/
```

Comment: This doesn't work in either Python 2 or 3. You should either change `input` to `raw_input` or use `print` as a function. Also, change `len(max(s,key=len))` into `max(map(len,s))` and get rid of the space before `for i in s[1:]` to save 5 chars

Comment: I've checked in the past using `input()` and assuming the text is entered as a string is usually permissable. I'll squeeze your other suggestions in later. Thanks :)

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr If you assume the input in a slightly different format you should: 1) Ask if it is admissable to the OP, 2) State it somewhere. Also, when doing this, I think it would be correct to also provide a sample that uses the format explained in the question.

Comment: @Bakuriu Done!!

Comment: I count 165 characters (+2=167 total).

Comment: @Doorknob Top row should be `=` symbols, not `-`, correct?

Comment: @Jeff Yes, that's what it says in the spec.

Comment: @Doorknob Thats been fixed, no change in score!

Comment: @Lego Ok, but I still count 165, not 166.

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 66 bytes

```
≔∕Ｓ|ι≔⁺⌈ＥιＬκ²ς/×=ς↓\↓⁺Ｌι¹←/←ς↑\↑⁺Ｌι¹↘Ｍ∕⁻ςＬ§ι⁰¦²→Ｐ§ι⁰Ｍ±²¦¹Ｐ×=ςＭ↘✂ι¹
```

My first Charcoal answer!

I wasn't getting a proper result with reflection, so I made the box manually.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5//9R55RHHVPf79lcc24niN2461FPx/s9S8/tfL9nzbldhzadb9I/PN32fNOjtskxQAxUAJLYeWjno7YJ@kAMkpkIlJmILDPj/Z61QGMfNe4@3wQUPLQcaHjjhkPLDm161Dbp/Z4NUAGgqkMbD20CigNt2wC2BqSxbcajOU0gg/7/NzQyNjE1M7ewNKgBM2sQAkBWTUFmak1BfkliSX5NaV5mcn5RHgA)

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal) (Verbose), 385 bytes

```
Assign(Divide(InputString,"|"),i)
Assign(Add(max(Each(i,Length(k))),2),v)
Print("/")
Print(Times("=",v))
Print(:Down,"\\")
Print(:Down,Length(i)+1)
Print(:Left,"/")
Print(:Left, v)
Print(:Up, "\\")
Print(:Up,Length(i)+1)
Move(:DownRight)
Move(Minus(v,Length(AtIndex(i,0)))/2,:Right)
MultiPrint(AtIndex(i,0))
Move(Negate(2),1)
MultiPrint(Times("=",v))
Move(:DownRight)
Print(Slice(i,1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY/LasMwEEX3@YqglURlErtvQxeGdBFISmnaXTaqPbGHOpKxZTUF/bsqajut6G64c3RGN69EmytRO5d1HZaSrtBgAXQtm17vdIuy5MQSxpHNRiIrCnoUJ/oo8ooi34AsdUU/GGM8Ydyw2bN/pSlZkGl8xSN0lDwQv52ydKU@JSf7PQmTUYfsIj4vNnDQ/I9vCObnU@lbw@eBygeBaKsMDAdesKz0GGxR9h01E5rptSzg5DstfZlFwtMJ7muNgzlgBssTlEID9d3jAA1b//vBAO1qzMHbYsaci5PLq@ub27v7pf0Z7W/gJ9sg2EZpoZXtJeaqlS4yLooKMNC@qw4PX98)

Comment: Nice answer! Unrelated: How many of you got my 1+ Christmas gift on 12/25/2020?

Comment: I don't remember getting one, I think

Comment: That's pretty sad, I worked hard on that one :( it's an 1+ chirstmas tree program I posted on twtxt :)

Comment: @null haven't checked twtxt in a while. I'll see it!

Comment: Tell Lyxal I'm back ;)

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, 292

```
import Data.List.Split
z=replicate
l=length
p w s=' ':s++z(w-l s)' '
c w s=p w$z(div(w-l s-1)2)' '++s
t(i:s)=let r=z m;m=(+)1$maximum$map l(i:s)in"/="++r '='++"\\\n"++"|"++c m i++"|\n|="++r '='++"|\n"++concat['|':p m x++"|\n"|x<-s]++"\\-"++r '-'++"/"
main=do l<-getLine;putStrLn$t$splitOn"|"l
```

… I’m a little new to this one :D

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 60 bytes

```
\|/DvLG⇧D\=*\/p\\+,„h⋏\|pǏ,:\|$-Ǐ,‹£Ḣƛ¥↲ðp\|pǏ,;¥›\=*\\p\/+,
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%5C%7C%2FDvLG%E2%87%A7D%5C%3D*%5C%2Fp%5C%5C%2B%2C%E2%80%9Eh%E2%8B%8F%5C%7Cp%C7%8F%2C%3A%5C%7C%24-%C7%8F%2C%E2%80%B9%C2%A3%E1%B8%A2%C6%9B%C2%A5%E2%86%B2%C3%B0p%5C%7Cp%C7%8F%2C%3B%C2%A5%E2%80%BA%5C%3D*%5C%5Cp%5C%2F%2B%2C&inputs=1234567890%7C12345%7C1234567890123%7Cpie%7Cpotato%7Cunicorn&header=&footer=)

Longer than I'd like...

Answer (score 1):

## C# 4.5 - <strike>375</strike> 347 chars

`;)` [If someone is interested to see how C# differs from others]

---

```
var c = input.Split('|').ToList();
int l = c.Select(s => s.Length).Max() + 2;
Console.WriteLine("/{0}\\\r\n| {1} |\r\n|{0}|\r\n{2}\r\n\\{3}/\r\n", "=".PadRight(l, '='), c[0].PadLeft(c[0].Length + ((l - c[0].Length) / 2)-1).PadRight(l-2), string.Join("\r\n", c.Select(s => "| " + s.PadRight(l - 2) + " |").Skip(1)), "-".PadRight(l, '-'));
```

---

Comment: You can save a **LOT** of characters by using one-char variable names and removing all that whitespace...

Comment: I might be wrong but I always assume that a complete program is required unless the OP states that a code snippet is acceptable. This is a long way from a complete program.

Comment: Brought it down to 305 simply by renaming variables and removing whitespace: `var c=input.Split('|').ToList();int l=c.Select(s=>s.Length).Max()+2;Console.WriteLine("/{0}\\\r\n| {1} |\r\n|{0}|\r\n{2}\r\n\\{3}/\r\n","=".PadRight(l,'='),c[0].PadLeft(c[0].Length+((l-c[0].Length)/2)-1).PadRight(l-2),string.Join("\r\n",c.Select(s=>"| "+s.PadRight(-2)+" |").Skip(1)),"-".PadRight(l,'-'));`

Comment: Thanks Doorknob. Can't we recognize minimum functions calls instead of total chars? That helps us [includes solutions providers also]. Because after sometime [after a year], it would be hard to understand code written by me and that also helps others to understand code easily.

Comment: The whole point of code golf is to solve a task in the least amount of characters... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf

Comment: Please somebody edit the initial answers. This is god damned goal of the code golf to use a minimum amount of chars. Not to preserve readability and maintainability over the years

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript, <del>373</del> 364

```
l="length";m=" ";a="\\";b="/";c="|";p=m+c;v="join";u="concat";o=[];q=Array;i=prompt().split(c);j=i.slice().sort(function(d,e){return e[l]-d[l]})[0][l]+3;i=i.map(function(d,e){s=q(o[l]=0|(e?j-d[l]-1:(j-d[l])/2))[v](m);return(e?p:c+s+(d[l]&1?m:""))+d+(e?s:s+m)+p});x=q(o[l]=j)[v]("=");r=[b+x+a,i.shift(),c+x+c][u](i)[u](a+q(o[l]=j)[v]("-")+b);console.log(r[v]("\n"))
```

Output

```
/===============\
|  1234567890   | 
|===============|
| 12345         | 
| 1234567890123 | 
| pie           | 
| potato        | 
| unicorn       | 
\---------------/
```

<sub>Edit Notes:

Thanks @Doorknob!: -9 Characters =)</sub>

Comment: There should be a lot of space for golfing left

Comment: Some things I see: `o={length:0}` --> `o=[]` (-8 chars), `p="| "` --> `p=c+m` (-1 char)

Comment: @Doorknob Oh... thanks =), i just wonder right now why i added `length` at all, that makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

## Java - <s>549</s> <s>492</s> <s>468</s> <s>453</s> 432

```
class a{static<T>void p(T p){System.out.println(p);}public static void main(String[]a){String b="/=";int l=0,t,i;a=a[0].split("\\|");for(String s:a)l=(t=s.length())>l?t:l;for(t=0;t<l;t++)b+="=";b+="=\\";p(b);i=a[0].length();p(String.format("| %"+(l+i)/2+"s%"+(l-i)/2+"s |",a[0]," "));b="|=";for(t=0;t<l;t++)b+="=";b+="=|";p(b);for(t=1;t<a.length;t++)p(String.format("| %-"+l+"s |",a[t]));b="\\-";for(t=0;t<l;t++)b+="-";b+="-/";p(b);}}
```

**With line breaks and tabs**

```
class a{
    
    static<T>void p(T p){System.out.println(p);}

    public static void main(String[]a){
        a=a[0].split("\\|");
        String b="/=";
        int l=0,t,i;

        for(String s:a)l=(t=s.length())>l?t:l;
        
        for(t=0;t<l;t++)b+="=";
        b+="=\\";
        p(b);
        
        p(String.format("| %"+(l+i)/2+"s%"+(l-i)/2+"s |",a[0]," "));
        
        b="|=";
        for(t=0;t<l;t++)b+="=";
        b+="=|";
        p(b);
        
        for(t=1;t<a.length;t++)p(String.format("| %-"+l+"s |",a[t]));
        
        b="\\-";
        for(t=0;t<l;t++)b+="-";
        b+="-/";
        p(b);
    }
}
```